# How can we parse a string to date using Dateformatter in strict mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, dateformatter

I am trying to parse a string say "04-06-2018" using Dateformatter with set format "dd/MM/yyyy". Notice the delimiter in the string is '-' but not '/'. But Dateformatter parses correctly. I don't want this smartness from Dateformatter. How can I enable strict mode for formatting like in **moment** library in JS.

Comment: If you dont want it, you can check it with regex. If the string has not format "xx-xx-xxxx", just do nothing

Comment: @QuocNguyen yeah, but I have about 13 formats to parse to and with reg-ex has to consider leap year etc.